# how can i fix this error "Error: Could not find or load main class" in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to run this code but i am always getting this error and there is nothing wrong with the code or the path.

I already tried to restart eclipse and i also tried to run this code on different ways. The error keeps coming.

```
package h3;

public class MijnKlasse_q1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int i = 2;
    if (i > 0)
    {
      System.out.print("X");
      System.out.print("Y");
    }
    if (i > 3)
    {
      System.out.print("Z");
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        System.out.print("N");
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.print("Y");
    }
  }
}
```

...\Java\QuizMaster\src\h3 this is the file structure where i keep the files. 
I made sure the file is named MijnKlasse_q1.java.

Comment: Did you try running : `java h3.MijnKlasse_q1` from the \src\ directory?

Comment: I tried that but that also doesn't work

Comment: Is `QuizMaster` a Java Project as Eclipse understands them? Why *should* it be able to find the `h3.MijnKlasse_q1` class?

Comment: Yes quizmaster is the project,
i think i found the problem, the JAVA files do not appear in the bin folder as a class file, someone know how or why this happend and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine.
Sometimes eclipse is acting weird.
I recommend that you try to copy the code to another new project and try to run it again.if this persist you can reinstall eclipse and try it again.

Comment: i think i found the problem, the JAVA files do not appear in the bin folder as a class file, someone know how or why this happend and how i can fix this?

Comment: with eclipse,my first recommendation is almost always to reinstall everything.if this is not possible,try to create a new project with this code,and finally,the last step is to move to a better IDE than eclipse.